# Is 'registrar' a built-in contract?

Tags: name-registrar

The [Design and issue your own cryptocurrency](https://www.ethereum.org/token) tutorial introduces `registrar` to create address aliases.

Is `registrar` a built-in contract reference?
Why does tab completion for *r* not suggest it? 
Are there any other such contracts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**  An Ethereum Request for Comment (ERC) titled "Default Ethereum Name Registrar" is on Github so it is in progress.  The primary author is Alex Van de Sande (avsa@ethdev.com) who is employed by the Ethereum Foundation and is directly working on Mist.

There are official precompiled contracts which include cryptographic functions such as ecrecover, sha256, ripemd160, and they are at addresses 1, 2, 3 respectively.  There is also an identity contract at address 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are at addresses 1, 2, 3..."? Where can I find the code on GitHub

Comment: @T9b Here you go https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/blob/master/libethereum/ChainParams.cpp#L46

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, it was commented out of geth (no idea of eth), I think the developers were not ready to commit to any certain registrar. (Or maybe just trying to delay the entire idea from happening.)

In my opinion, it should happen sooner rather than later, it would be nice to remember a short name rather than 0x1234566732348234923...

Comment: Thanks. I must have had an outdated version of `geth`.